# How do I connect a string/char variable that is written via Scanner into a variable of a other class?

Tags: java, class, java.util.scanner, transfer

I want to change that player variable but somehow I cant change it. In this Array Field, there is only '^' no matter what i give into that scanner.

```
Field.FeldAusgeben();
System.out.println("Führen Sie eine Aktion( g = vorwärts gehen, l = links gehen, r = rechts drehen, q = beenden ");
System.out.print("Eingabe: ");
decision = sc.next().charAt(0);

public void setplayer(char decision)
{
    player = decision;
}

//2 Dimensionales Feld
    char [] [] Field = {{'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'},
                    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'},
                    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'},
                    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'},
                    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', player, ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'},
                    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'},
                    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'},
                    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'},
                    {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'}};

public void FeldAusgeben() 
{
    for( int i = 0; i < Field.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < Field[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(Field [i] [j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is because you seem to be confused about when and how initialization of objects happens. The initialization of the field `char [] [] Field` happens only once right when the the object the field belongs to is created. It will then take the value of `player` at that very moment and initialize its array like that. It will not care if the `player` variable later changes as it is already done with initializing itself. You need to manually change the array by reassigning the values. For example `Field[2][4] = 'X'`

Answer (score 0):

Private class variables can be set by public constructors or methods, like setters.  A string from Scanner.next() can be used as an argument to either, or the constructor/method can do the scanning.